# Modify Top.Links in magento

Tags: php, html, xml, magento, templates

I have a magento installation with a top link i wish to remove on the very right (the one without an image here: http://tinyurl.com/lz5ouss ). This has been previously setup by someone else and i'm not sure quite how they have done it. There is no local.xml file in the layout folder for the template and I have checked top.phtml and top.links.phtml and the link has not been hardcoded in there either. I was just wondering if anyone can suggest where i could remove this from?

Comment: It could be being done by an Observer from some extension.  Have you tried grepping for a call to the "addLink" function?

Answer (score 1):

For a quick fix:

```
.lz_cbl { display: none;}
```

Beyond that try turning on template path hints to find out what's populating it.

Comment: Yeah might just do that , for some reason template path hints isn't working either on this template so am having quite bit of difficulty working this template out

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple way, you can just hide your div by following steps

Go to your `object-source-skin.css` file search for line no `150`

In `free-delivery` class add this : `display:none;`

Answer (score 0):

Go to your theme css file and add following css to hide the top right link having no image.

```
.quick-access li:last-child{
        display:none;
}
```